# google container engine having problems pulling image from container registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I'm trying to create a deployment on GKE (running 1.6.0) which is looking like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<IMAGE>:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: production
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

Creating this fails with the following error message:

```
Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<IMAGE>:latest": rpc error: code = 2 desc = failed to register layer: rename /var/lib/docker/image/overlay/layerdb/tmp/layer-629814250 /var/lib/docker/image/overlay/layerdb/sha256/bd2793152ee77e9d503e981352ff16122b220968ce9df1cc3b49b9704d7dfe28: directory not empty
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "api" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = failed to register layer: rename /var/lib/docker/image/overlay/layerdb/tmp/layer-629814250 /var/lib/docker/image/overlay/layerdb/sha256/bd2793152ee77e9d503e981352ff16122b220968ce9df1cc3b49b9704d7dfe28: directory not empty"
```

Other deployments that look almost identical but use a different image are working as expected. What is wrong with the image I'm trying to pull? And how can I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be caused by a [known docker bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23184) where shutdown occurs before the content is synced to disk on layer creation. The [fix](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/25523) is included in docker v1.13.

One temporary workaround [sugguested](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23487#issuecomment-230170252) is to remove the empty files in the directory, and re-pull the image.

Comment: yes, this really seems to be a bug. downgrading to kubernetes 1.5.6 sets up the deployment as expected.